# Compiling C++ code on Mac

Tags: c++, gcc, namespaces, std

I want to write very simple C++ programs on my Mac but I get errors. I don't have a lot of experience with C++ (and gcc) and the simple guides on the web also don't discuss this topic.

Please have a look at my simple hello world program:

```
erik2:~[03:38 pm]$ cat hw.cpp 
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
  cout<<"Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
erik2:~[03:38 pm]$ gcc hw.cpp 
hw.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
hw.cpp:5: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
```

Responding to the answers until now (thanks a lot), I put back(!) the namespace declaratation, but that doesn't result in a success, though:

```
erik2:~[03:51 pm]$ cat hw.cpp 
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
  cout<<"Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
erik2:~[03:51 pm]$ gcc hw.cpp 
Undefined symbols:
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      ___gxx_personality_v0$non_lazy_ptr in ccphDFtO.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      ___tcf_0 in ccphDFtO.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<<     <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)",     referenced from:
      _main in ccphDFtO.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in ccphDFtO.o
  "std::cout", referenced from:
      __ZSt4cout$non_lazy_ptr in ccphDFtO.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Basing on the [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq), this question is off-topic.

Comment: Besides the `using namespace std;`, you should use the command `g++` instead of `gcc` to compile C++ programs.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Thanks and sorry for not reading them ahead of posting there!

Comment: @Jesper: I thought gcc is the basic compiler manager that will choose the according compiler by itself. Is that wrong?

Comment: @erikb: I'm not 100% sure on OS X, but on Linux you have to use `g++` for C++ programs, otherwise it will not link with the correct libraries and you'll get things like those "undefined symbols" errors you're seeing.

Comment: @Jesper: Yes, seems to be the same. So that was my actual problem, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to either add

```
using namespace std;
```

or qualify your use of symbols from that namespace as in

```
std::cout << "Hello, world!";
```

so make the symbol visible (and you also want to add a newline....).

Comment: had that before but removed it because it showed really weired and not understandable errors. Seems I need to do something about them instead. Thanks

Comment: Yes, for starters *using the correct compiler* such as `g++` rather than `gcc` should help.

Comment: @erikb, Dirk's right, the cause of the second set of errors is that `gcc` doesn't know where the c++ libraries are, but `g++` does, so you get linker errors as indicated by `ld: symbol(s) not found`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; // <<< you forgot this !

int main ()
{
  cout<<"Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add     using namespace std;

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  cout<<"Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```