# How do you compile C++ on a mac?

Tags: c++

I cant figure out how to compile on a Mac. Writing code in sublime, any help appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling C++ code on Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582154/compiling-c-code-on-mac)

Answer (score 0):

Open the command prompt and type `g++ 'yourprogram.c'` and it should compile and leave you with an executable called a.exe or something like that. Run the executable by typing `./a.exe`.

Comment: You might mention what to do if that command fails because `g++` isn't found.